# Displaying a png image through a php script

Tags: php, png

I would like to display an image through a PHP script so that you have a normal img in html but with a source of a php script. This script would then open an existing png or jpg image and display that image through it.

I have been trying this code with no luck at present.

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("logo.png");

header("Content-type: image/png");

imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

No errors the image output is broken.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any other output in your script?  Is there any whitespace before `<?php`?

Comment: No errors the image output is broken.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
readfile("$file");
exit;
```

it is good idea to add some headers, like:

```
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

look at discussion here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: @aHunter If your file already is a PNG and you want to display it as PNG, all you need to do it *output* it. No need for gd at all here, `readfile` (which outputs a file to the client) is fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put die(); at the end of your code. Otherwise you will output extra data which will result in errors in image.

Comment: I have tried this but the image output is still broken. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Unless the script has more content that explicitly outputs something, it won't ouput "extra data".